# openlayers updating a layer based upon viewable area

Tags: ajax, openlayers

For a project we are wishing to use use openlayers. I know how to plot points and have a popup bubble. However since there is going to be quite a lot of points plotted on the map for the UK. What i am wanting to do is send the central point of the viewable area and in the backend send a layer update of all the points in the current viewable area. In openlayers is there anyway of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can either use a WMS server to serve maps as images, or use the [BBOX Strategy](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/BBOX-js.html) to only get the content within the viewport.